# django Drive API python

Tags: python

can anyone help? how to upload the file into folder (not folder id) with folder name ?
is it possible to do?(python) Google Drive API python

if you want to do more ,

how to do it in  django application uploaded the file into the google drive with specified folder  and renaming the file ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is it possible to send the file with folder name in Google drive API python?  in django web application